# Excel formula in Python takes too long to process

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to apply an excel formula that compares sheets 1 & 2 to determine available price updates, once determined applies the new price on sheet 3.

The formula is referenced in this article: https://www.get-digital-help.com/automate-excel-update-list-with-new-values-array-formula.

The script takes too long 15-20 minutes to process and doesn't apply the formula down the sheet.

Please help!

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('New-Price.xlsx', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Sheet3']



for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws['C2:C'+str(ws.max_row)],2):
    cellObj[0].value = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$2001, 0)), INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5000, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5000, 0)), INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$2001, MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$2001, 0)))".format(i)
    wb.save('New-Price.xlsm')
```

Comment: Do you have to use openpyxl? Using xlwings will achieve what you need quite simply in a few lines though the use of lists/dictionaries without messing with excel formulas

Comment: It is no wonder things take so long if you save the file every step of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've excel files looking like this -

**1st File**

|  | product | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | product1 | $10 |
| 1 | product2 | $20 |
| 2 | product3 | $30 |
| 3 | product4 | $40 |

**2nd File**

|  | product | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | product1 | 20 |
| 1 | product2 | 10 |

Notice the price column in the 1st file contains $character. We need to do some preprocessing to remove that dollar sign.
Let's load these 2 excel files into pandas dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('<replace the string with file1 path>', dtype=str)
df2 = pd.read_excel('<replace the string with file2 path>', dtype=str)
```

Let's preprocess 1st dataframe now and convert the datatype of the price column in both the dataframes-

```
df1['price'] = df1['price'].str.replace('$', '').astype(float) #do this processing when the price column contains dollar sign.
df2['price'] = df2['price'].astype(float)
```

Now, dataframe 1 is an old dataframe that contains all the products, and old prices dataframe 2 contains fewer products with their updated prices. So, we can do a left merge.

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='product', how='left').rename(columns={"price_x": "old_price", "price_y": "new_price"})
```

This is the output after the merge -

```
|   | product  | old_price | new_price |
|---|----------|-----------|-----------|
| 0 | product1 | 10        | 20.0      |
| 1 | product2 | 20        | 10.0      |
| 2 | product3 | 30        | NaN       |
| 3 | product4 | 40        | NaN       |
```

Now we can subtract column 'new_price' with column 'old_price' to get the final_price.

```
merged_df['final_price'] = merged_df['new_price'] - merged_df['old_price']
```

The final dataframe will look like this -

|  | product | old_price | new_price | final_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | product1 | 10 | 20.0 | 10.0 |
| 1 | product2 | 20 | 10.0 | -10.0 |
| 2 | product3 | 30 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | product4 | 40 | NaN | NaN |

you can save this into excel using -

```
merged_df.to_excel('<path to your output file>', index=False)
```

**NOTE :** you can drop the useless columns before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing!!! Thanks for putting this together so quickly. Are you able to adjust the Final price so that it defaults to the new price and applies the old price to the corresponding (final price) blank cells

In order words the expected output would look like this.

|  | product | old_price | new_price | final_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | product1 | 10 | 20.0 | 20.0 |
| 1 | product2 | 20 | 10.0 | 10.0 |
| 2 | product3 | 30 | NaN | 30 |
| 3 | product4 | 40 | NaN | 40 |